# Ignorar archivos al hacer git merge

Tags: php, git, github, vps

Buenas noches tengo una duda y no encuentro nada por internet de momento.

¿Como puedo hacer un *git merge* pero ignorando unos archivos?

Ejemplo:

En database.php de la rama *main*, tengo las credenciales del servidor VPS, ya que cuando se actualiza la rama *main* automáticamente se actualiza en el VPS.

Y tengo otra rama que es local y en database.php donde tengo las credenciales de local.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que, cuando se realice el cambio en la rama local y me cambie la rama main para hacer merge, se ignore el archivo database.php?

Answer (score 3):

lo que buscas podría ser utilizar un `.gitignore`. Si tienes un fichero en especifico lo añades, siempre cuando no lo añadas con un `git add` pudiendo hacer un `git reset nombreFichero` para hacer un unstage. Te dejo unas [templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore) de ejemplo para que puedas tener referencia.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Lol, están buenísimas las templates!

Answer (score 1):

Mi sugerencia es que no tengas tus claves en un archivo que sea accesible a tu repo, sino que uses otro método como un almacenamiento remoto seguro y acceso con OAuth 2.0, o declarar una variable de entorno con la ruta del archivo. Por ejemplo:

```
export CREDENTIALS_PATH="/home/usuario/credenciales.json"
```

De esa manera, en tu archivo *database.php* vas a poder leer de esa ruta indicada en la variable de entorno, sin necesidad de exponerlas dentro de tu código. Algo así como: `$credendials = getenv(CREDENTIALS_PATH);`

Ahora, para contestar tu pregunta y en caso que por accidente o mala práctica **tengas las credenciales en tu repo**, como escribió @ICodeForCaffeine, puedes indicarle a `git` que ignore ese archivo y **no lo añada al index**:

```
$ git rm --cached credenciales.json
```

Esto se hace suponiendo que ya tienes el archivo en tu índice, es decir, ya se le dio un `git add`. Si no, entonces no pasa nada y sólo te arroja un error insignificante.

Ya con esto, el archivo sigue existiendo en tu workspace, pero ya no lo sigue git. Osea, existe en tu folder local, pero no en tu repo.

Y luego añades el nombre de ese archivo en un archivo `.gitignore`:

```
credenciales.json
```

Y luego de eso, después de hacer `git add .` o cualquier commit, o push, lo que sea, ese archivo se va a ignorar.

**Esto mismo tienes que hacer en tu entorno de producción**, es decir, tienes que setear la variable de entorno con la ruta con las credenciales en tu entorno de producción.

**Por nada del mundo expongas tus credenciales en un lugar accesible al repo**.

Estuve en un caso donde un chico hizo un repo local en el antiguo Github (público por defecto), y el vato guardó un json credentials de GCP en ese repo ¡Pensando que 1) Era privado, 2) Las credenciales tenían pocos permisos!.

Luego unos bots crawlearon ese json credentials, y con esas credenciales y permisos, comenzaron a crear clusters de kubernetes para minar monero. La empresa perdió tremendo varo y el pibe tuvo que irse.

Las credenciales guárdalas alejadas del lugar del código. Hay varias herramientas para mantenerlas alejadas:

- Vault
- Ponerlas en una variable de entorno
- Google Secrets Manager

Entre otras.

Comment: Cuidado con git rm --cached, me quiere sonar que a algunos les borra el fichero del repositorio aunque este en el gitignore. Pero puedo estar errado, por lo demás explicación perfecta!

Comment: rm --cached lo borra del índice y del repo, pero no del workspace. Puse eso suponiendo que el archivo de las credenciales ya estaba siendo seguido por git

Comment: Deja lo aclaro.